# Sending slash command to specific guild channel

Tags: python, discord, discord.py

this is my first time using python and I've been trying to make a selfbot that would send a slash command to a specific guild channel on startup with discord py for like 5 hours now and I have no idea what I'm doing, does anybody know how to specify a server and channel when sending a message/command or a reliable way to send slash commands that isn't reliant on a discontinued library that doesn't work anymore

I tried going through threads on here aswell as the discord py library to figure out how to do it but I haven't found anything at all

Comment: self-bots are against discord TOS and it's unlikely you'll get much help because of it. Slash commands are only available to actual bots using bot tokens/applications so if you're not doing that then you won't get much luck.

Answer (score 0):

You can get the ID of a channel if you enable Developer Mode in the settings on Discord:[image]

Then you can right click on a channel to copy its ID:

[image]

I python you can use discord.py. For example:

```py
import discord

client = discord.Client()
@client.event
async def on_ready():
    print('Logged in as', client.user)
    channel = client.get_channel(ChannelID)
    await channel.send('/command')
    await client.close()
    
client.run('token')
```

Here you need to replace `ChannelID` with your channel ID and `token` with your Discord Bot's token.

If you want to use your account (not recommended) you can pass `bot=False` in `client.run`:

```py
client.run('token', bot=False)
```

To get your account's token, you need to load Discord from a browser (I use Chrome to demonstrate);
Press `F12` or `Ctrl+Shift+I`, to open devtools;
Switch to the `Network` tab;
Filter the keyword `messages`;
Open a channel in discord, and a request will be sent to `/api/v9/channels/-channel_ID-/messages?limit=50`.
Look at that request (click on it, and then switch to `Headers` tab);
Scroll down to `Request headers`, and grab your token.

[image]